# Efficiently and quickly finding matching rows in two large two dimensional arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two large 2 dimensional arrays (million rows): `newData` and `existingData`.

I need to find rows in `newData` that are also in `existingData` based on values in a matching column, and if a match in `existingData` is found, update some columns in `newData`.

For the sake of example:

## `newData`:

| date | lookup | junk | junk | junk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | b | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | a | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | d | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | c | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

## `existingData`:

| date | lookup | junk | junk | junk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | f | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | c | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to compare the 2nd column and update `newData` with the value of the 1st column in `existingData`. So, after the loop is done, it would look like:

| date | lookup | junk | junk | junk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | b | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | c | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | d | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Note: The order of the rows in the final table does not matter.**

I need the script to be as efficient as possible as CPU compute is a limited resource for me.

I haven't figured out where to start. My thought is something like this:

1. sort both tables on the 2nd column
2. loop through each row in `newData` and for each row:

   1. do a binary search for `newData[i][1]` (the 2nd column) in the 2nd column of `existingData`
   2. if a result is found, update the column in `newData

The thing is, for every loop (#2) the binary search will start from the first row of `existingData`. There is no point in searching all of the rows of `existingData` because both arrays are sorted and we know the next row of `newData` cannot be EARLIR in the `existingData` table. Let me explain.

After sorting, both tables look like:

## `newData`:

| date | lookup | junk | junk | junk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | a | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | b | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | c | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | d | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

## `existingData`:

| date | lookup | junk | junk | junk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | c | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | f | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

In the first loop of `newData` we'll look for `a` in the 2nd column of `existingData` and find it is on row 1.

So then on the next loop of `newData`, when we look for `b`, there is no need to start looking from row 0 of `existingData`.

My issue is, I'm struggling to find a way to make this all work.

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: I'm so lost, I don't even have code worth sharing. Like, I don't know where to start. Conceptually I get what I have to do -- I just don't know how to do it.